# Relationship between cross entropy and focal loss function

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, loss-functions

> If the multiple categorical cross entropy loss function is given by
>
> $$ L_{CE} = -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^K X_{ik}log(Y_{ik})$$
>   where $X$ is the labelled data and $Y$ is model prediction for pixel $i$ of an image and $K$ classes.
>
> Then how can i modify this using the same variables to get the focal loss function? I know it is a modification of the cross entropy loss, but the focal is commonly written in terms of the probability $p_t$ for the class with each label i.e.
>
> $$ L_{FL} = -(1-p_t)^{\gamma}log(p_t)$$
>
> for some tuning parameter $\gamma$.. But it doesn't seem to be of the form of $X$ and $Y$?

I have seen another article use

$$ L_{FL} = -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^K Y_{ik}(1-p_t)^{\gamma}log(p_t)$$
is this the correct form?

Note it seems $p_t = (1 * Y * X) + ((1 - Y) * (1 - X)) =2XY - X-Y+1$.

Comment: Without stating what the focal loss function is, it's hard to answer this question.

Comment: Sure thing.. adjusted

Comment: (Your cross entropy formula is missing a minus sign.) // Just note for mutually-exclusive classes, $X_{ik}$ takes the value 1 only once, and is 0 otherwise. Once we make that simplification, we can see that $L_{FL}$ introduces a new weighting term $(1-p_t)^\gamma$.